# создание файла на SD карте

Tags: java, android

7 версия на реальном телефоне, 10 на эмуляторе. пытаюсь просто произвести запись на съёмную SD карту. в манифесте прописал стандартные разрешение на запись и чтение. Так же приложение делает запрос на проверку разрешения.
добываю список хранилищ:

```
File path = new File("storage/");   
for(File file : path.listFiles()){
   куда нибудь записываю
}
```

в моём случае получается список:

```
storage/0584-8477    съёмный накопитель физический
/storage/emulated    несъёмный emulated  + /0
/storage/self        несъёмный emulated  + /primary
```

в несъёмные дописывал путь, всё записывается, но почему то каждый из них является одним физическим. А вот со съёмным никак не получается Permission denied.
 так же пробовал через mnt/:

```
File path = new File("mnt/");  

mnt/ext_sdcard       съёмный  
mnt/sdcard           несъёмный
```

и таже самая история. на съёмный опять Permission denied. 
 Вывод сделал только такой что физические хранилища эмулируются что бы на прямую на них нельзя было записать, поэтому и два разных пути записи на них. Но со съёмным носителем ничего, подскажите почему у Меня не получается.
 Ещё добавлю, читал что обращение к хранилищам запрещено если они подключены через USB к компьютеру, а так как Я на реальном устройстве занимался отладкой то как бы нельзя было обратиться к SD карте, отключал от компьютера телефон один фиг таже ситуация.

Comment: Укажите вашу версию Android, например в версии 4.4 это "фирменный" баг.

Comment: на телефоне стоит 7 версия. на эмуляторе 10.

Comment: гляньте [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/1891712). Начиная с шестерки нужно отдельно запрашивать разрешение у пользователя.

Comment: Здравствуй. при запуске приложения сделал проверку запроса, и запрос на запись/чтение, но всё равно тоже самое. Разрешение отрабатывает как положено, но запись почему то запрещена, хотя смотреть что находится в директориях и бегать по ним можно. Но если убрать разрешение и отказать в разрешение при запросе, то уже серфить по папкам не получится так как вернёт пустой path.listFile(), или всё таки надо прямо всё по инструкции сделать как указано по ссылке которую Вы указали?